# Node.js on a remote server: io is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm building an application that links to a node.js hosted on my home computer (78.233.79.103:8000)

The server is properly istalled (if you go to the addres I gave you'll se the socket.io works)
If I run the server in localhost with

```
node server.js
```

all is good, the application works

Then when I run the application on my other pc or on my iPad (I wrapped it with phoneGap so it's just a web app included in a native iOS app), trying to connect the io on 78.233.79.103:8000 i got the console log:

```
io is not defined
```

here is my sourcecode: https://github.com/synbioz/puissance4

look for the server.js

I know I only call io = require('socket.io').listen(PORT); but kwnow also I should create something like:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8000, '78.233.79.103');
```

that actually doesn't works

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

probably because .listen()  doesn't return `this`.

try writing them in separate lines.

```
var io = require('socket.io');
io.listen(PORT);
```

Comment: It is alray in, not? io = require('socket.io').listen(PORT);  If I try your solution this give me: This returns me ' Cannot call method 'on' of undefined when I run node server.js

Comment: sorry, you mean the client side? please check if your client loaded `socket.io/socket.io.js` correctly. `io` should be defined there.

Comment: client side I have: <script src="78:233:79:103:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js" /> (and if I want it to work with local node server I change it in <script src="http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js" />)